Using discord.js and plain Javascript (no JQuery, etc.), how can I make a Discord bot direct-message a PDF to a new user from guildMemberAdd event?
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client ();

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.send("Welcome to the server!");  //This works.
    member.send(files: ['./docs/test.pdf']);   //The colon after 'files' here disallowed the node.js application to run
    
    //The following 3 lines are added solely for the purpose of clarifying my question:

    console.log("New member joined:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(member) + "\n\n");
    console.log("member.userId -> " + member.userId);
    console.log("member.guild.id -> " + member.guild.id);   //Other information I found suggests this is the way to get the member's user ID, but it also doesn't work.

});

bot.login('TOKEN_HERE');

This is running in a Node.js environment.  Output of the above if I comment out 'member.send(files...' (sensitive data replaced with X's):

New member joined:
{"guildId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","joinedTimestamp":1715968452501,"premiumSinceTimestamp":null,"nickname":null,"pending":false,"communicationDisabledUntilTimestamp":null,"userId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","avatar":null,"flags":0,"displayName":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","roles":["xxxxxxxxxxxxx"],"avatarURL":null,"displayAvatarURL":"https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/5.png"}
member.userId -> undefined
member.guild.id -> undefined

Obviously, member.send doesn't support sending files the way message.send or channel.send would.  In the guildMemberAdd event, I don't have access to any message on which to .send as I would in, say, a messageCreate event.
My goal here is to be able to direct-message the newly-joined member a PDF file.  As an alternative (which I'd like to avoid if possible), IF I could get the new member's user ID inside of the guildMemberAdd event (which I also can't seem to accomplish), then I have a different way I could potentially send the PDF.
I've tried multiple variations of the shown code and was expecting the application to run and send newly-joined member the test.pdf file in a direct message, in the same manner as would occur if a human user were sending a file via direct message to another human user, either by clicking Discord's "+" sign next to message input field and attaching a file to the message, or by copying a file and pasting it into the message field.
Thanks in advance for any help!

If you still need help, for your member.send line please change it to member.send({ files: ['./docs/test.pdf'] });, this is because it expects a type extending an object as an argument which is why you need the file: in front of it.
Also for accessing the user id, I would use member.user.id instead, and you are missing client intents, so you will not be able to access users I believe.
